# List/matrix is not saving the correct values

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have a weird problem with an assignment I got. We are supposed to implement a matrix class. Well, it's not that hard, but Python just won't do as I tell it to. But I'm sure there is an explanation.

The problem is that, in the following code, I try to save values (provided in a list) into a matrix.

```
class simplematrix:
    matrix = [[]]
    def __init__(self, * args):
       lm = args[0]
       ln = args[1]
       values = args[2]
       self.matrix = [[0]*ln]*lm

       for m in range(lm):
           for n in range(ln):
               self.matrix[m][n] = values[(m*ln)+n]

vals = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
a = simplematrix(2,3,vals)
```

When I try to print the matrix, I expect to get [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]], which I get if I run it by hand, on a piece of paper. If I print the matrix from Python I get [[3,4,5],[3,4,5]] instead.
Can anyone tell me why Python acts like this, or if I made some stupid mistake somewhere? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `[[0]*ln]*lm`. The result consists of `lm` **references to the same list**, so when you modify one row, all rows appear to change.

Try:

```
self.matrix = [[0]*ln for i in xrange(lm)]
```

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks a lot for the fast answer and the explanation. I don't see the use of making references to the same list multiple times, so I would never have figured it out myself :)
Once again - thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome. Everyone gets caught out by this at some point.

Answer (score 2):

The answers by Tim and aix correct your mistake, but that step isn't even necessary, you can do the whole thing in one line using a list comprehension:

```
self.matrix = [[values[m*ln+n] for n in range(ln)] for m in range(lm)]
```

You can also say:

```
vals = range(6)
```

as opposed to what you already have. This tidies up your code and makes it more Pythonic.

Comment: Wow, that's compact, but much nicer. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: No problem, that's the beauty of Python for you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `self.matrix = [[0]*ln]*lm` doesn't give you a list of `lm` separate sublists, but a list of `lm` references to the single same list `[[0]*ln]`.

Try

```
self.matrix = [[0]*ln for i in range(lm)]
```

(If you're on Python 2, use `xrange(lm)` instead).

Comment: Whats the difference between xrange and range?

Comment: xrange essentially only stores the list elements when it needs to, so if you are using data with large list structures, a lot less memory is used up. It's actually a bit more complicated in that xrange returns an xrange object rather than a list, but as far as you need to know, it's for reducing memory use.